# unable to execute mysql query in perl while connecting to remote server

Tags: mysql, perl

I have connected to one MySQL database which have been hosted in a remote server in Perl. Now I am trying to execute a select statement on a table in subject.pl file using Perl command line. The code is

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use DBI;
use strict;

# Connected to mysql audit database in dev server
my $dsn = 'DBI:mysql:Driver={mysql}';
my $host = 'dev-mysql.learn.local';
my $database = 'subject';
my $user = 'testUser';
my $auth = 'testPassword';
my $dbh = DBI->connect("$dsn;host=$host;Database=$database",$user,$auth) or die            "Database connection not made: $DBI::errstr";

# Prepare query
my $sql = "SELECT
        subject_id
        ,subject_value
    FROM
        subject";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);

#Execute the statement
$sth->execute() or die "Unable to execute".$sth->errstr;

while (my @row = $sth->fetchrow_array()) {
   my ($subject_id, $subject_value ) = @row;
   print "$subject_id,$subject_value,$subject_db_field\n";
}

$sth->finish();
```

I am getting error at line `$sth->execute() or die "Unable to execute".$sth->errstr;`

The error message is `Unable to execute at D:\Demo\perl_demo\subject.pl line 24.`

But when I am printing the $dbh variable, its giving the result like `DBI::db=HASH(0x1ca7884)`. So I guess the connection is establishing properly.

Please help me to fix this issue as I am completely new in Perl scripting.

Comment: Did you check the return value of $dbh->prepare($sql) ?

Comment: you surely have connection as otherwise it would die at connect (`connect.. or die ..`)

Comment: Yes Frank, I have checked the return value of $dbh->prepare($sql). Its giving `DBI::db=HASH(0x1ca74f4)`

Answer (score 1):

Check for errors on `prepare`,

```
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbh->errstr;
```

Comment: I have checked with pitting your code. But its not throwing any error. When I print the $sth variable, its giving result like `DBI::db=HASH(0x1ca74f4)`

Comment: @KanhuCharanSahu it is strange that `$sth->execute() or die $sth->errstr;` doesn't report actual error message?

Comment: is it due to the remote database?

Comment: @KanhuCharanSahu no, `DBI` should always have error message when something fails.

Comment: @KanhuCharanSahu you can set `{RaiseError => 1}` as fourth argument to `connect`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41611/discussion-between-kanhu-charan-sahu-and-mpapec)